# GET API created using lambda service and API gateway working from postman but not from browser

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.6, aws-api-gateway, http-status-code-400

I created an GET method API for qr-code generation with the help of Lambda service( using python 3.6) and API gateway.

API is working from both postman and from browser when I pass the simple query-string parameter.

> For ex. :   https://xxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/DEV/qrcode/?data=umaprasad

This gives me correct qr code.

When I pass **JSON data in query-string parameter** for the same API it work from **Postman** perfectly 
but when I call the same **API from chrome browser, HTTP ERROR 400 occur**.

> https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com/dev/qr-code-generator/?data={"sample_key":"sample_value"}

[image: API Error]

I allowed the CORS headers too.

How to overcome this problem ?

Comment: Me too facing exactly the same issue @umaprasad-bisen :( Found any reason or solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to escape the json while sending it in query string like this?

```
{%22sample_key%22:%22sample_value%22}
```

Postman does that for you be default so may that is why it is working.

By the way sending `POST` suits more when sending the json instead of `GET`. I am not sure what your use case is.

Comment: As soon as I put { (curly braces) in query string it gives error. some special symbols are working though.

Answer (score 0):

In our use case we wanted to make call this URL inside `image` tag of the *HTML*. so we made it work using **encodeURIComponent** function call of javascript to URL encode the data part of it so that API Gateway gets the input in required format.

Sample example below:-

```
<html>
    <body> 
        <img src='base_url?data='<script>b</script'>
    </body>
    <script> 
            let a = {"name":"vinit"}
            let b = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(a))
     </script>
</html>
```